# Insert to std::vector of string, list pair

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector

I want to add elements into `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::list<std::string>> > m_Vec;`

with a function like

```
void setVec(const std::string &node, const std::string &value) 
{
    m_Vec.emplace_back(node, ???);    
}
```

How can I insert the list string values to my vector of pairs?

Should look like:

```
"id1" -> list of string values
"id2" -> list of string values
...
"id10" -> list of string values
```

The order is here important!

Comment: What do you want to be inserted into the vector? Your vector contains pairs of `string, list<string>` but your function only has two string arguments.

Comment: Build up the list of strings with this function (add not all string values at once)!

Comment: How about giving an example so that we don't have to guess?

Comment: What is unclear? The set function is given

Comment: So every time you call the function you want to add the string `value` to list  where the first part of the pair is the same as `node`?  If so you need a `map` not a `vector`

Comment: And btw. if you immediately downvote questions here on stackoverflow fewer and fewer people will ask!

Comment: @leon22 you say that you want to insert "the list string values" to your vector. That much is clear. But there is no list in your example code, so it's unclear what you want to insert.

Comment: PLEASE LOOK AT THE DEFINITION OF THE VECTOR -> FIRST LINE! There is a list

Comment: I don't "immediately downvote", I downvoted because it's an unclear question where you refuse to clarify (e.g. by giving an example).

Comment: Please look at the comments and see that we are confused.  Maybe you need to add some explanation/pseudo code of what you want to have happen so when know what you want.

Comment: @NathanOliver We had a map in the past, but the problem is that we insert id values and have the wrong order (id1, id10, id2, id3...) and I can't add zeros or work with integers!

Comment: Maybe show how the vector should look like after a couple calls to the function.

Comment: @leon22 Then why not ask how to fix that instead of asking question and make us guess how it should work?

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried to ask this and got downvoted! So we decided to work with a std::vector of pairs e.g. id1 -> list of strings, id2 -> list of strings, ... id10 -> list of strings. The order is important!

Comment: The reason you have ???'s there is not because of a problem in how to write the code.  The reason you have ???'s there is because of a problem in design.  You can't write code for something if you don't know what it is supposed to do.  You should be able to express what you want it to do in words before you put it in code.

Comment: @KennyOstrom OMG. I only want to retrieve somehow the stored list of my vector with idX and add the new string value to it. Look at my comment and function prototype!

Comment: Oh, so just get rid of the list.  The value is a string, and the vector is pair (node, value).  Do you also need to be able to access elements by name, as well as preserve the order?

Comment: @KennyOstrom The order is the problem why I cant use a std::map -> look at my edits!

Comment: OMG? Oh you're mad at me because nobody can read your question.  Heh. Okay, trying again.  It sounds more like a multi-map, now.  So you have a map of name, value pairs.  You add a duplicate entry for one of the names, so now the value must contain a list of both values, in order (and the order you do not get from multimap)?

Comment: Don't expect to get useful answers if you rudely dismiss questions in the comments instead of clarifying your question. Even your edit does not show a real example of inputs and outputs.

Comment: I'd probably change it to a map < string, list<string>>.  To insert, find or create the existing name, get its list, then append the value to that list.  I'm not testing and posting an answer because you were mean to me, and I have to go cry.

Comment: @leon22 I still think you should have asked how to get the map version to work correctly instead of this but I digress.  If you still want the map approach then check this out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e18199f500b5688

Comment: @NathanOliver Thx Nathan. But I can't understand why the people here are so crude and downvote immediately the questions (if some details are missing I always try to edit my question)! It's no fun anymore. I hope the mood will be better in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I insert the list string values to my vector of pairs?

First, create a list:

```
std::list<std::string> a_list;
```

Then add as many strings into your list as you want to. Here, I add a single string:

```
a_list.emplace_back("I am a string");
```

Finally, you can copy-initialize the list in the pair:

```
m_Vec.emplace_back(node, a_list);
```

The above is for exposition. The copying can be avoided and all this can be condensed to:

```
m_Vec.emplace_back(node, std::list<std::string>{"I am a string"});
```